# Method createIndex() not callable on a collection

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, collections

In the doc of the `createIndex` they say `db.collection.createIndex(keys, options)` so i call `createIndex()` with the code below. The name of my database is `articles` and the name of the collection is `bce`. Inside `bce` there is already a document with the field `article`.

```
class Stockage():
    def __init__(self):
        self.connexion()

    def connexion(self):
        client = pymongo.MongoClient("localhost", 27017)
        self.bce = client.articles.bce

sql = Stockage()
sql.bce.createIndex({article : "text"})
```

And i have the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1132-fc8762d315d1>", line 1, in <module>
    sql.bce.createIndex({article : "text"})

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 3321, in __call__
    self.__name.split(".")[-1])

TypeError: 'Collection' object is not callable. If you meant to call the 'createIndex' method on a 'Collection' object it is failing because no such method exists.
```

Is not `bce` a collection ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is because in Pymongo the method is called `create_index()` instead of `createIndex()` as it is named in the `mongo` shell.

It also has a different format for the parameter compared to its `mongo` shell counterpart. Instead of accepting a document/dict as index specification, it accepts a list of tuples instead. This is because you cannot guarantee the ordering of dict keys in Python.

So the correct line should be:

```
sql.bce.create_index([("article", pymongo.TEXT)])
```

More details are available in the [Pymongo Collection](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html) page.